# Graph, vertex cover problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph, a set $T \subseteq V$ of nodes it's called vertex cover if every edge $e \in E$ has a vertex in $T$.

**The MVC Problem:**

- *Input:*

  - The graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ nodes.
  - A number $k \in \mathbb{N}, k \le n$.
- *Output:* Yes if there exists a vertex cover $T$ with $|T| \le k$, No otherwise.

This problem is in $\mathcal{NP}$.

How do we show the following algorithm is correct for MVC?

$R-COV(G,k)$

$if(E = \emptyset$ then **return *("Yes", $\emptyset$)***

$if(|E| \gt k * (|V| - 1)$ then **return *("No")***

Let ${u, v} \in E$

$if( R-COV(G - u, k - 1) == ("Yes", T) )$ then **return("Yes", $T \cup\{u\}$)**

else $if( R-COV(G - v, k - 1) == ("Yes", T)$ then **return ("Yes", $T \cup \{v\}$)**

else **return ("No")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will assume that G is a simple undirected graph.
R-COV(G, k) returns "Yes" if G has a vertex cover of at most k nodes.

The first line of the algorithm says that if G has no edges then the answer is "Yes" since a set of 0 nodes would be a vertex cover for G in this case.

Now consider the second line.
Consider a set of k nodes.
Each node can be connected to at most n-1 other nodes.
So, a set of k nodes can cover at most k(n-1) edges.
So, the answer must be no if G has more than k(n-1) edges.

Now consider any edge (u, v) in G.
Let T be a set of k nodes.
If T is a vertex cover for G, at least one of u or v must be in T.
If we remove either u or v from G, we remove all edges that u or v are part of respectively from G to get G'
This means we can remove u or v from T to get a set of (k-1) nodes that form a vertex cover for G'.
This is why R-COV(G, k) returns "Yes" if R-COV(G-u, k-1) or R-COV(G-v, k-1) returns "Yes".

If R-COV(G-u, k-1) and R-COV(G-v, k-1) both return "No", it means that u and v are both not in T. That means the edge (u, v) is not covered by T.
This means that T is not a vertex cover for G.
Hence, the final else returns "No".

Now consider the time complexity when k is not an input but a constant.
The line "Let u, v $\in$ E" iterates over all edges in G.
There can't be more than $\binom{n}{2}$ edges which is $O(n^2)$.
At each edge iteration, there are at most 2 recursive calls (one each for the u and v cases).
These recursive calls form a binary tree of depth at most k-1 (with the root being at depth 0).
The max number of nodes(i.e. recursive calls) in the tree is $2^k - 1$. 
So, the algorithm is $O(2^kn^2)$ or $O(n^2)$ if k is constant and small relative to n.

Comment: Hi, what is the time complexity on this algorithm and if _k_ is a constat how can we show that it has polynomial time?

Comment: have edited the answer to include time complexity.

Comment: Thank you. There can't be more then $\binom{n}{2}$ edges? Is this correct?

Comment: Da mă, e corect. Un graf complet are maxim n(n-1)/2 muchii.