# Cover of vertices - NP Algorithm analysis, correctness and execution time

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

**Introduction**
Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, we call a set $T \subseteq V$ a **cover** if any edge $e \in E$ has one extremity in T.

**Decision Problem**: Given $G = (V, E)$ with n nodes and a $k \le n$, return *Yes* if there exists a set **T** which is a **cover** in G, with $|T| \le k$, *No* otherwise.

Ok, so far so good. I'm given the following algorithm(it returns Yes/No & the set T):

$R-COV(G,k)$

$if(E = \emptyset$ then **return *("Yes", $\emptyset$)***

$if(|E| \gt k * (|V| - 1)$ then **return *("No")***

Let ${u, v} \in E$

$if( R-COV(G - u, k - 1) == ("Yes", T) )$ then **return("Yes", $T \cup\{u\}$)**

else $if( R-COV(G - v, k - 1) == ("Yes", T)$ then **return ("Yes", $T \cup \{v\}$)**

else **return ("No")**

I shall prove that this algorithm does exactly what's asked to do (so it is correct) and find out it's $T(n, k)$ (execution time).

**What I know by now**

Guessing right, this decision problem is NP-complete.

To prove it is correct, I thought of analyzing every condition in this algorithm and proving that it returns "Yes" only for T-covers.. Visually it looks right, but I don't know how to write it down mathematically..

For the execution time, should I use the Master Theorem? Is it apropriate? Also I think that when k is constant, the algorithm is, obviously, running in polynomial time. But how should I write this down mathematically?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is $R$ in your algorithm? Also you don't want to say an algorithm is NP-complete, it's the decision problem which is NP-complete.

Comment: The proof of correctness of the algorithm is given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514974/graph-vertex-cover-problem/1515135#1515135

Comment: @user137481, thank you very much